# How to mock a Sequelize transaction with Sinon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, sinon

I'm testing a function that creates a resource using Sequelize, I'm adding transactions because I want to commit everything if there are no errors, I have this

```
const createResource = async (resource) => {
  const t = await sequelize.transaction();
  try {

    const createdResource = await Resource.create(resource, { transaction: t });

    await t.commit();
    return createdResource;
    
  } catch (err) {
    await t.rollback();
    throw err;
  }
};
```

The unit test for the function above, looks like this

```
it('Should create a resource with no errors', function () {
    const dummy = aDummy();
    const createFake = sinon.fake.resolves({ dataValues: dummy });
    sinon.replace(Resource, 'create', createFake);
    return ResourceService.createResource(dummy)
        .then(res => {
            expect(res).to.not.be.undefined;
            expect(createFake.calledWith(dummy));
            expect(createFake.calledOnce).to.be.true;
        });
});
```

What I want is not to depend on any infrastructure at all, so my problem is that I don't know how to mock a Sequelize transaction with Sinon

Comment: I wouldn't unit test that function, the whole thing would be very implementation-dependent and running against a test double of a complex API you don't own. Having this abstraction layer gives you very clean tests for the _consumers_ of the `createResource` function, where the test double is a simpler interface that you own, but this function itself should probably be tested at more of an integration or functional level.

Comment: But even if I test it in a higher level, it'd make a call to a database, which I don't want because my test would be depending on an infrastructure

Comment: The test depends on the database because _the behaviour_ depends on the database. You don't test this at a higher level of abstraction because it's expressing a low level of abstraction.